# CSV, merge multiple rows data into single row and into the same column

Tags: php, mysql, csv

```
media_gallery_image         category        sku         created_at          price
/c/u/cutting_shafts.jpg     Specials        01mb        3/19/2013 22:59     1487
/s/h/shred_bin_3.jpg        Cross Cut 
/e/c/ecc_switch_3.jpg       Destroyit 
/2/6/2604ccm.jpg            Commercial 
                            Paper Phoenix
```

These are the details of one product in CSV file. For this product, its showing me a sku, creation date, price and multiple categories & gallery images.

Now the problem is that its showing first media gallery image, first category, sku as 01mb, date as 3/19/2013 22:59, price as 1487 in one row,

then in 2nd row it shows 2nd gallery image, 2nd category, sku as blank, date as blank, price as blank

then in 3rd row(same as 2nd row) and so on.

I have 100s of products this way, they all have multiple images, categories but not showing in the same product data row as above. I want to merge all the media gallery images in same row and in the same column separated with comma(,). For example **`"/c/u/cutting_shafts.jpg, /s/h/shred_bin_3.jpg, /e/c/ecc_switch_3.jpg, /2/6/2604ccm.jpg"`**

and same for the categories column.

Is it possible to do this by editing and updating CSV through php?

### UPDATE

Below is the screen shot of what is needed:-
[image]

Comment: You mean via the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function?

Comment: Well, I have to update CSV file back after merging the rows. There is nothing to do with mysql at the moment

Comment: I don't understand: you wish to merge several groups of rows in  single ones in your csv file?

Comment: I have added a screenshot, I hope it can help to understand the issue.

Comment: @didierc - Yes, there are products with different number of images and categories, these are not same for all.

Comment: People here usually expect askers to show a little bit what they tried, but anyway, interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

The following performs something similar to a group by and coalesce on columns specified as parameters. It may be used to do what you want:

```
<?php

function setup_row($groups, $row){
  $res = $row;
  array_map(function($v) use(&$res,$row){
      $res[$v] = array($row[$v]);
    },$groups);
  return $res;
}

function concat_row($groups, $coalesces, $row, &$merge){
  array_map(function($v) use ($row, &$merge) {
      if (isset($row[$v]) && $row[$v] != "")
        $merge[$v][] = $row[$v]; // add to group concat columns
    },$groups);
  array_map(function($v) use ($row, &$merge) {
      if (isset($row[$v]) && $row[$v] != "")
        $merge[$v] = $row[$v]; // coalesce columns
    },$coalesces);
}

function implode_row($groups, $merge){
  array_map(function($v) use (&$merge) {
      $merge[$v] = implode(',', $merge[$v]);
    },$groups);
  return $merge;
}

function csv_group_by($groups, $coalesces, $group_by, $infile, $outfile){
  $current_group = "";
  $result;
  if (($hin = fopen($infile, "r")) !== FALSE &&
      ($hout = fopen($outfile, "w")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($hin, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      if ($row[$group_by] != $current_group){
        if (isset($merge)){
          $result = implode_row($groups, $merge);
          fputcsv($hout, $result,',');
        }
        $merge = setup_row($groups, $row);
      } else {
        concat_row($groups, $coalesces, $row, $merge);
      }
    }
    if (isset($merge)){
      $result = implode_row($groups, $merge);
      fputcsv($hout, $result,',');
    }
    fclose($hin);
    fclose($hout);
  }
}

csv_group_by(array(1,2), array(), array(5),”infile”,"outfile");

?>
```

Replace `outfile` and `outfile` by the file names you want in the last line.

Or replace the end of the script, after the functions with

```
If (count($argv) == 3)
    csv_group_by(array(1,2), array(), array(5),$argv[1],$argv[2]);

?>
```

And call the script at the command line as follow:

```
$ php script.php <infile> <outfile>
```

Where `<infile>` and `<outfile>` have the expected meanings.

Oh, and the script expects csv files to be comma separated, you'll have to edit the code to change that behaviour.